# Why my c++14 program for removing repeated characters is giving extra characters in the ouput?

Tags: c++, string, hash, c++14

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    string s,str;
    cin>>s;
    int a[26]={0};
    for(int i=0;i<26;i++){
        int x=(int)s[i]-97;
        if(a[x]==0){
            a[x]++;
            str+=s[i];
        }
    }
    cout<<str<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Input : geeksforgeeks

Ouput:geksfor 
�

This is where i am getting some extra characters as ouput  why i am getting like that?
Can anyone help me ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "97" - What does this magic number mean?

Comment: `s[i]` - Are you sure that `i` is going to be in range?

Comment: Or, to put it another way, why are you looping to 26 instead of the length of the string?

Comment: Are you sure `a[x]` is going to be in range? Even simple programs can become confusing when the data does not match assumptions. Some degree of "parameter validation" is always advisable. In general, if you give the users instructions on how to use a program, you are going to write some code assuming that they are following those instructions. That's fine but there should be checks between the users and such code. It's helpful to the users but even more helpful to the programmers.

Comment: I hope nobody provides you with any uppercase characters, or else this code will crash.

Answer (score 4):

Your loop runs with `i` in range `[0, 26)`, where `i` is indexing `s`, regardless of the length of `s` (and in this case, `s` is *much* shorter than 26 character long). Eventually, you index outside the bounds of `s` (invoking undefined behavior) and start processing gibberish, and your code starts pushing unique gibberish onto your result string. If you can assume your inputs are always lowercase ASCII, you could iterate with `i` in range `[0, s.size())` (or use C++11 for-each style looping without indexing at all), but short-circuit out if `str` reaches a length of 26 (because all 26 unique characters have been seen).

One approach:

```
int main(){
    string s,str;
    cin>>s;
    int a[26]={0};
    for(auto c : s){
        int x = c-97;
        if (a[x] == 0) {
            a[x]++;
            str += c;
            if (str.size() == 26) break;
        }
    }
    cout<<str<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

I think you have consider the input string in lower case letters.
But one mistake you have done in the code is that you are iterating the for loop for only 26 times. 
But lets consider the string such that the letters are repeated after 26th character. There only your code fails. So, you just have to iterate through the whole string.
The correct code is:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string s,str;
    cin>>s;
    int a[26]={0};
    for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++)
    {
        int x=(int)s[i]-97;
        if(a[x]==0)
        {
            a[x]++;
            str+=s[i];
        }
    }
    cout<<str;
    return 0;   
}
```